# R spaces between graph and tables beneath

Tags: r

I have one plot and two tables and now it look like this:

https://filebin.net/jo8i12yuamuiaq52

and i am not happy that the graph got squished and the tables a re so separated from each other. I would like to put the graph little down and the tables more together, i was trying to change some (grid arrange ) but i can't figure it out, i guess fro experience users its dsmall think to correct, please help my plots to be pretty again!

```
 pdf("ABCTransporter_subset_descr.pdf")
 IDs<-unique(ABCtransporter_subset_GnoG_melt$X1)
 for (i in 1:length(IDs)){
 temp <-   ABCtransporter_subset_GnoG_melt[(ABCtransporter_subset_GnoG_melt$X1)==IDs[i],]
temp <- summarySE(temp, measurevar="value", groupvars=("Category"))

p_value_no_G <- p_value_ABCtransporter_no_G[(   p_value_ABCtransporter_no_G$V1)==IDs[i],]
p_value_G <- p_value_ABCtransporter_G[( p_value_ABCtransporter_G$V1)==IDs[i],]
p_value_G_noG<- p_value_ABCtransporter_G_noG[( p_value_ABCtransporter_G_noG$V1)==IDs[i],]


p <-ggplot(temp, aes(x=Category, y=value, fill=Category))+
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se),
              colour="grey", width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
              position=position_dodge(.7))+
ggtitle(IDs[i])


 #p_value_no_G
 p_value_no_G <- as.data.frame(p_value_no_G)

 tt <- ttheme_default(colhead=list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)))
 tt <- ttheme_default(base_size = 6, base_colour = "black", base_family = "",
                   parse = FALSE, padding = unit(c(2, 2), "mm"))

 colnames(p_value_no_G) <- c("X", "protein", "CTROL_ABC.7", "CTROL_ABC.8", "CTROL_ABC.7.8", "ABC.7_ABC.8",  
                          "ABC.7_ABC.7.8", "ABC.8_ABC.7.8", "names")
 tbl <- tableGrob(p_value_no_G, theme=tt)
 tbl<- na.omit(tbl)
 #p_value_G 
 p_value_G <- as.data.frame(p_value_G)

 tt <- ttheme_default(colhead=list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)))
 tt <- ttheme_default(base_size = 6, base_colour = "black", base_family = "",
                   parse = FALSE, padding = unit(c(2, 2), "mm"))

 colnames(p_value_G) <- c("X", "protein", "CTROL.G_ABC.7.G", "CTROL.G_ABC.8.G", "CTROL.G_ABC.7.8.G", "ABC.7.G_ABC.8.G",  "ABC.7.G_ABC.7.8.G", "ABC.8.G_ABC.7.8.G", "names")
 tblG <- tableGrob(p_value_G, theme=tt)
 tblG<- na.omit(tblG)

 #p_value_G_noG
 p_value_G_noG <- as.data.frame(p_value_G_noG)

 tt <- ttheme_default(colhead=list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)))
 tt <- ttheme_default(base_size = 6, base_colour = "black", base_family = "",
                   parse = FALSE, padding = unit(c(2, 2), "mm"))

 colnames(p_value_G_noG) <- c("X", "protein", "CTROL_CTROL.G", "ABC.7_ABC.7.G", "ABC.8_ABC.8.G",  "ABC.7.8_ABC.7.8.G", "names")
 tblG_noG <- tableGrob(p_value_G_noG, theme=tt)
 tblG_noG<- na.omit(tblG_noG)


 grid.arrange(p, tbl, tblG,tblG_noG, ncol=1,)

}
dev.off()
```

data to mess around with:
https://filebin.net/veqabrs8jxkybkjb

Comment: I can't reproduce your data to mess with it myself, but something like `grid.arrange(p, tbl, tblG, tblG_noG, ncol = 1, heights = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))`?  That lets you scale the heights of various grid.arranged objects.  Alternatively, set a `margin` argument in grid.arrange to reduce the spacing between them

Comment: so simple and so genious. thanks a lot! i will play with the parameters